# Create an installer (or a dmg) which executes the shell script in the packaged contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, shell

I have created a template for iOS applications. For the template to be visible under Xcode File->New->project , I will have to place the *.xctemplate folder in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/[category_name]. To automate this, I have written a shell script, which copies *.xctemplate folder into the required location (on any mac machine). It works fine. The user has to run the script to make the template available under xcode.

Now my requirement is to create an installer or a dmg, on click of which the shell script to copy contents to destination must be triggered automatically. The shell script and the template folder has to be packaged. I tried creating a dmg , but that doesn't trigger the script within it automatically, or I am unaware of any such methods.

Or an installer to copy contents to destination folder would also be helpful. Is there a way, i could create such installer or a dmg for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://codevarium.gameka.com.br/how-to-create-your-own-beautiful-dmg-files/) shows step-by-step how to create DMGs with a free software, a terminal and the finder.

Answer (score 0):

I used the packageMaker tool to create an installer. packageMaker comes as an auxiliary tool along with xcode. It can be downloaded from apple developer site provided one has an apple ID.

Steps on how to use a packageMaker is available in the below mentioned site,

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFgQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.filibeto.org%2Funix%2Fmacos%2Flib%2Fdev%2Fdocumentation%2FDeveloperTools%2FConceptual%2FPackageMakerUserGuide%2FPackageMaker_UserGuide.pdf&ei=sG9FUqmADIeVrAe68oCoCQ&usg=AFQjCNEj5VJzHbZbnmJlseff-kd33H1kbw&cad=rja

Thank you